# I need to convert a single input string into a dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I need to convert a single input string into a dictionary with its place indices as keys and the letters as values in python. But I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

```
r = list("abcdef")    
print (r)    
for index,char in enumerate(r,0):    
indd = str(index)    
print(indd)    
abc = indd.split(",")    
list2 = list(abc)   
d = dict(zip(list2,r))    
print(d)
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly.

Comment: Are you looking for `d = dict(enumerate('abcdef'))`?

Comment: do you actually want the keys to be strings or numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `range`.

**Demo:**

```
r = list("abcdef")
d = {}
for i in range(len(r)):
    d[i] = r[i]
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}
```

Or a simpler approach using `dict()`.

```
r = list("abcdef")
d = dict(zip(range(len(r)), r))
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string `abcdef`.

First make a list of tuples having first element of tuple as place index and second element of the tuple as the letter at that index. This can be done in this way:

```
tuples = list(enumerate("abcdef"))
```

Now, using the dictionary constructor, convert this list of tuples to a dictionary as given below:

```
dict(tuples)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> dict(list(enumerate("abcdef")))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}
```